# SAPUI5 - Routing with parameter

Tags: routes, sapui5, sap-fiori

I have 2 pages. On first page, user needs to select dropdown values & click submit, Where I call jQuery ajax. On success, I need to pass the response to page 2. Below is what I have tried. But it doesn't works.

firstPage.controller.js

```
jQuery.ajax({
url: requestUriOutput,
method: "GET",
async: false,
dataType: "json",
success: function(data) {
if(data.d.results.length > 0)
    {
        var detail = data.d.results.concat();
        var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
        oRouter.navTo("second", {details : detail});
    }
} });
```

SecondPage.controller.js

```
    onInit: function () {
            var oRouters = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
            oRouters.getRoute("second").attachPatternMatched(this._onObjectMatched, this);
        },
        _onObjectMatched: function (oEvent) {
            var obj = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").details;
        },
```

manifest.json

```
    "routes": [{
            "pattern": "",
            "name": "app",
            "target": "app"
        }, {
            "pattern": "first",
            "name": "first",
            "target": "first"
        }, {
            "pattern": "second/{details}",
            "name": "second",
            "target": "second"
        }],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to navigate to route with name `"table"`, but your `manifest.json` doesn't contain a route with this name. Align route names and try again.

Check the URL of the webpage; it should change after the data is downloaded. If it doesn't change, make sure that `router` is initialized in your `Component.js` `init()` function: `this.getRouter().initialize()`.

**Edit:**
Based on the provided code, you are trying to add an array as URL parameter. This is not supported, you should pass only string parameters or encode the whole array and decode in the second view.
Routing definition is also incorrect; if you want to use targets, you should define a target object as you can see [here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/e5200ee755f344c8aef8efcbab3308fb.html). If you don't want to use targets, change the property name `"target"` to `"view"` in the `Router` constructor (note that it's now deprecated, so I'd recommend to use a Component and/or manifest.json to define routing with targets).

Comment: sorry it was editing mistake. In actual code, I have passed it correctly. I have also checked `component.js` & the router is initialized. But still It returns the error "Cannot read property 'length' of null"

Comment: @Yal Could you post your code (for example using JSBin)? Have you checked the URL after you got the error message? Did it contain the details parameter?

Comment: I have added my code here. Please refer [JsBin](https://jsbin.com/muxuco/edit?html,console,output)

Comment: `@nistv4n` Thanks for the information !! Now I have declared a model globally & have set the JSONModel in the first page & retrieved data back in the second page. It worked. Also in my workspace, I have used targets within manifest.json.